# How can I trigger a function when server starts using keystonejs?

Tags: node.js, express, cron, keystonejs

I am using Keystonejs to make a small app. I want to print out a message every second since the server starts, so I use node-cron to handle this task.

```
function(){
        var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
        new CronJob('* * * * * *', function() {
            console.log('You will see this message every second');
        }, null, true, 'America/Los_Angeles');
}
```

However, I don't know where I should put this code to make sure that when server starts, this function will be triggered.

Can you help me with this problem? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1):

you can alter your [lib/core/start.js](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/blob/master/lib/core/start.js#L22) file to also execute that callback

Comment: Modifying source code is generally to be avoided.

Comment: of course, but often you need to dig in, especially with immature tech